# Install dart from homebrew

Tags: dart, homebrew, failed-installation

I tried to install dart language from homebrew (Mac) following by the instructions at webdev.dartlang.com

`$ brew tap dart-lang/dart`

`$ brew install dart`

and got an error:

Error: The following formula
  dart
cannot be installed as binary package and must be built from source.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install

and i have no idea how to install dart in other way. please help!

Comment: Have you tried `xcode-select --install` and then `brew install dart` again?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you very much! problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install homebrew again from:

```
https://brew.sh/
```

and than,

```
https://webdev.dartlang.org/guides/get-started
```

Make sure, on terminal you do all the task with root access.
I faced this issue before, and solve with the above steps.
Hope this helps! :)